# Connecting RDS from EC2 with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, connectivity

I am new to AWS. I have one EC2 instance and one RDS instance. I have everything installed and ports opened on both of them. 
I could able connect to my EC2 instance with PuTTy and able to FTP with WinSCP and is all good.
I could even be able to login to my RDS instance and check all my databases from my computer with mysql CLI. 
But my php pages in EC2 instance and not communicating with RDS instance. I don't know why?
I even tried to connect from my ec2 instance normally using mysql command and I achieved that. But not through my php file.

Error that I am getting, when I am trying to connect is 
Access denied for user 'ec2-user'@'.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal' (using password: YES)

Have anyone faced this type of connectivity problem earlier, could any one help me to achieve this,

Addition: Hi, I observed that my EC2 instance is in location southeast-1a and my RDS in southeast-1b. But with my RDS I don't have any option to choose availability zone as I enabled Multi-AZ option. Hope if that helps a bit more.

Thanks,
Murali.

Comment: Did you modify the RDS security group to allow access from your EC2 instance?

Comment: yes, I did. I authorized my EC2 security group on my RDS instance security group with my AccoutNumber. Thanks birryree

Comment: I observed that my EC2 instance is in Availability zone southeast-1a. But my RDS instance is in Availability zone southeast-1b. Could that be any problem. I enabled Multi_AZ on my RDS instance. This disabled my availability zone option for that instance when I launched my RDS instance. Thanks!!!

Comment: try to connect to amazon RDS from the EC2 terminal using the mysql command line. it's much easier to debug it from there.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your help. I could able to connect through EC2 terminal. Then I came to know that I have some typo in my PHP file. It was now rectified. Thanks a lot for your time. Cheers Murali.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO 'ec2-user@'servername.ap-southeast-1.compte.internal' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

you may need to add additional permissions based on what you decide to grant

Comment: unfortunately the main user of RDS didn't have grant privileges.
Thanks,
Murali.

Comment: you mean nobody has grant privileges on the DB?